# Box2DWeb - What's the difference between a fixture definition and a body definition?

Tags: box2d

My question related to any version of Box2D,  though I am using Box2DWeb.js.

What is the difference between a fixture definition and a body definition? Why do you need both when creating a square?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

A body is made out of one or more fixtures. The fixture definitions contain information about *parts* of the body. e.g. friction, restitution, shape, etc.

The body definition contains information about the body as a whole. That includes things like gravity scale, if the body can sleep, is the body a bullet, etc.